# Get Height of inflated Linear Layout

Tags: android

I'm using this method [Android: Expand/collapse animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation) to have an expandable linearlayout inside my listview. My listview row have a shown linearlayout with a short description and when I click in this listview I call a AsyncTask to get the long description on the internet, inflate the hidden linearlayout of the row and expand to show the received data.

The problem is, if I set an target height to the hidden list view which is expanding, everything work just perfect, but I don't know how many data I will receive from the AsyncTask   so I need to get the height of the inflated hidden linearlayout.

I already tried:

- getHeight() -> returns 0.
- getMeasureHeight() ( [How to get or compute the width/height of an inflated view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430270/how-to-get-or-compute-the-width-height-of-an-inflated-view) ) - > returns 256 for just a textview (20px) inside it
- observer ( [Getting the height of an inflated Linearlayout at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832803/getting-the-height-of-an-inflated-linearlayout-at-runtime) ) enter in  a infinity loop.

Reading some material in web I found that the view just have an height after being drawned in the screen. So what is the best way to get this height to set as target of my expand layout?

I'm inflating and expanding the layout in the onPostExecute of my asyncTask.

Answer (score 2):

Consider posting a Runnable to the inflated View

```
final View view = findViewById(R.id.something);
view.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Height = "+view.getHeight());
        }
    });
```

This runnable stays on the event queue until the view is fully inflated, so that the getHeight() and getWidth() methods return non-zero values. Explanation by Romain Guy is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3602144/293847)

Comment: It didn't worked. The sequence I make in my app is: GET DATA> INFLATE A VIEW> INSERT THIS VIEW INTO HIDDENVIEW> EXPAND THE VIEW. As my hidden view have height 0 when I add the inflated view into it, the return height of the inflated view is 0 too